# android get current coordinates of edittext on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I need to get current coordinate of edittext on screen. I am using `OnGlobalLayoutListener`
but it is called two times instead of one time and another disadvantage that it called too late.
If any way how to get position of editText immediately when it was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use View.getLocationOnScreen() and/or getLocationInWindow(). **You can use in onWindowFocusChanged**

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        int[] locationInWindow = new int[2];
        object.getLocationInWindow(locationInWindow);

        Log.v("TAG","getLocationInWindow() - "+ locationInWindow[0] + " : " + locationInWindow[1]);
    }
```

Comment: When should these methods call? I have tried to call they from onCreate but they return 0(